# Not able to inspect elements on Web dialog page

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

When i opens a new "Dialog Web Page", i am not able to inspect the elements on this new "Dialog Web Page".Right click is also disabled on the that page.

I have tried to inspect that element using, Settings-->F12 Developer Tool option, but it inspects only parent window elements.

Comment: Do you mean if you click on the new window dialog and press F 12 not opening the developer tools for that dialog? Can you please try to provide your sample code which we can try to run on our side to check the issue? It can be helpful to understand the issue in better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Yes, and problem is that F12 gives source code of Parent window. May be it is like modal dialog box. and right click is disable to the website.

Comment: If it is a modal dialog than obviously it will show the source code of the window because modal dialog is not a separate page and it is a part of a current page. To verify it you can try to find the code for the model dialog in that source code. If you still have any confusion than you can share the site address if site is available publically or you can show some sample code which we can try to check.

Comment: It is like a web dialog page. I can not share the page because of security reasons.

Comment: In this specific issue, we cannot provide any solid suggestion without checking your code. So I am afraid we will not not be able to provide any further suggestion without any code. Thanks for your understanding.